# Instruction added to x86 CPU after release

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, intel, amd-processor

Has there ever been a case of an instruction *added* to an x86 CPU after release? That is, an instruction that didn't exist/work out of the box CPU, but could work on the same CPU sample after a microcode update?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208051/discussion-on-question-by-beeonrope-instruction-added-to-x86-cpu-after-release).

Comment: Some instructions may be not public at time of release. There was project https://github.com/xoreaxeaxeax/sandsifter to find which byte sequences and instruction spaces are recognized by instruction decoder. Text: https://github.com/xoreaxeaxeax/sandsifter/blob/master/references/domas_breaking_the_x86_isa_wp.pdf Also, Koppe's papers on microcode for old AMD https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/usenixsecurity17/sec17-koppe.pdf will give you some hints how microcode ROM and updates (patches) were organized long time ago.